# HTML parsing in FLUTTER for android / iOS development

Tags: android, html-parsing, flutter, html-parser

We know there is a Jsoup library for android developers to parse html text, code etc. As I am new in flutter mobile app development  I want to know if there is any library like Jsoup to parse html text,code from a web site in flutter.

Comment: It depends on your purpose. if you just want to display a webpage, use this plugin https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin . what is your use case which this plugin cannot do?

Comment: No, actually I want to display only a few text or content like a headline of a news from a newspaper website, not the full webpage.

Comment: Still, use that plugin, use md.

Answer (score 11):

You can parse a HTML string this way

```
import ‘package:html/parser.dart’;
//here goes the function 

String _parseHtmlString(String htmlString) {

var document = parse(htmlString);

String parsedString = parse(document.body.text).documentElement.text;

return parsedString;
}
```

Please let me know this doesn’t solve your problem.

Comment: The package in question to be added is -> html: ^0.14.0+4

Answer (score 2):

I solve the problem for me. Firstly, to user parser you should fetch data using `http.get(url)`. After that you can parse what you want.

Fetch html page:

```
Future<String> fetchHTML(String url) async {
  final response = await http.get(url);

  if (response.statusCode == 200)
    return response.body;
  else throw Exception('Failed');
}
```

After that you must call `FutureBuilder()`

```
    FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: fetchHTML('http://your_page.ru/page.html'),
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          //Your downloaded page
          _temp = snapshot.data;
          print(snapshot.data);
          return Text('Finished');
        }
        else if (snapshot.hasError)
          return Text('ERROR');

        return Text('LOADING');
      },
    ),
```

And now you can parse it:

```
parse(_temp);
```

Comment: hey i'm in your exact situation but the get functions throw me an error that i think is related to the request header but don't know how to fix. any idea?