# How can i remove html tags from a variable which i am calling from rest api and display it?

Tags: flutter

So basically I am calling get request on a rest API in flutter. I can display the data perfectly in listview but while doing so this particular data have lots of html tags in it. How can I possible remove the html tags after I have got the data in a variable?. The data has 
 tag in between two strings and there are other html tags as well. Here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_on_field/API/api.dart';
import 'package:flutter_on_field/Add/AddAttendance.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


class Attendance extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AttendanceState createState() => _AttendanceState();
}

class _AttendanceState extends State<Attendance> {


  List users = [];
  bool isLoading = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    this.fetchUser();
  }
  fetchUser() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    var uri = Uri.parse('https://hirana.in/cdnhira/Serv_onfield_v1/attendance_list?session=');
    var url = uri.replace(queryParameters: <String, String>{'session': session});
    print(url);

    var response = await http.get(url);
    // print(response.body);
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      var items = json.decode(response.body)['data'];
      setState(() {
        users = items;
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }else{
      users = [];
      isLoading = false;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title:Text("Attendance list",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,

      ),
      body:Stack(

        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              width: 2000.0,
              child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context,new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context)=>AddAttendance())
                );
              },
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: Text('Add Attendance',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),)),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Container(
            height: 720,
            child:getBody(),
          ),
        ]

      ),

    );
  }

  Widget getBody(){
    if(users.contains(null) || users.length < 0 || isLoading){
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),));
    }
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: users.length,
        itemBuilder: (context,index){
          return display(users[index]);
        });
  }
  Widget display(item){
    var date = item["attend_date"];
    var inTime = item['intime'];
    var outTime = item['outtime'];
    print(date);
    print("hi");
    return Card(
      elevation: 1.5,
      child: ListTile(
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              children: [
                Text("Date(Name)",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight:FontWeight.bold)),
                Text(date),

              ],
            ),

            Column(
              children: [
                Text("In Time", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight:FontWeight.bold)),
                Text(inTime),

              ],
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
                Text("Out Time", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight:FontWeight.bold)),
                Text(outTime),

              ],
            ),

          ],
        ),

      ),

    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the sample data (With HTML tags) and your expectations out of it?

Comment: Data which is coming - 13Oct2020 <br> (Somendra)

Comment: Data I want - 13Oct2020 (Somendra) and also if i can display the brackets in next line or separately.

Comment: another example = "<span style=''>03:45pm<\/span><br>(06:00pm)". I just want the time.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51800205/8553954

Comment: I am not able to add it to the code without the errors. Can you edit the code or write how to  call my variable in the function ?

Comment: Error: Could not resolve the package 'html' in 'package:html/parser.dart'.
I am getting this error even when I have added the dependcies

Answer (score 3):

> I am not able to add it to the code without the errors. Can you edit the code or write how to call my variable in the function.

You can use it like this:

```
import ‘package:html/parser.dart’;

// Some of the code.

String parseHtmlString(String htmlString) {

var document = parse(htmlString);

String parsedString = parse(document.body.text).documentElement.text;

return parsedString;
}

// Some of the code again.

if(response.statusCode == 200){
      var items = json.decode(response.body)['data'];
      items = parseHtmlString(items);
      setState(() {
        users = items;
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }else{
      users = [];
      isLoading = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the HTML package (https://pub.dev/packages/html), which already includes a parser:

```
import 'package:html/parser.dart' show parse;
import 'package:html/dom.dart';

main() {
  var document = parse(
      '<body>Hello world! <a href="www.html5rocks.com">HTML5 rocks!');
  print(document.outerHtml);
}
```